# Communication between kernel threads in a linux kernel module

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, ipc, kernel-module

I'm just beginning to learn the tricks of making a kernel module on linux kernel 2.6. What I'm looking to do is have 3 kernel threads, called the slaves, that need to send data to a 4th kernel thread, called master, and receive their respective responses. The slaves can request at any time, which means I will need some sort of a queue structure and a way to redirect responses to the correct thread.

First I looked at implementing my own queue structure to queue incoming requests - but how do I signal the master of this? I don't want the master to keep polling (as in the case of spinlocks/semaphores). I have a feeling there is a better way to communicate between threads.

Due to lack of documentation (and admittedly inferior searching skills), I'm at a loss on how to implement this. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing two distinct problems:

1. The actual communication between the slaves and the master. You can use the FIFO implementation in the kernel (`kernel/kfifo.c`).
2. You need demultiplexing for the master without busy-waiting/polling. You can do it just like in userspace, via poll/epoll on an "event file descriptor" (eventfd). Take a look at the kernel-level API in `include/linux/eventfd.h` (the implementation is in `fs/eventfd.h`).

You should probably use a [kfifo, event file] pair for each slave thread. The master thread blocks in a `do_poll()` call and, when woken up, is able to use the right FIFO based on the fd that was "signaled". Take a look at `fs/select.c` to have an idea about how you should call `do_poll()`.

You might want to use mutexes to guard the FIFO.